# How can I embed comments plugin to my own website?

Tags: comments, comment-form, comments-template

I am looking for a way to embed WordPress `comment form` to `watch.php` in order to allow user to comment on a specific video. Can you tell me how?

[image: Eaxample]

Comment: What kind of problems do you have? Did you try to include `<?php comments_template(); ?>` at all in that `template`? See the Codex for [more info](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comments_template/#source-code). A little research is appreciated before even asking some! Btw are you misusing wordpress.com or is that a mistaken `tag`?

Comment: Comments can be done on some object. Video should be post-type or attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at rendering a [`comment_form`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form). You can render it anywhere in your page template and there are lots of ways to customize it.

```
$comments_args = array (
    // change the title of send button
    'label_submit'        => 'Send',
    // change the title of the reply section
    'title_reply'         => 'Leave Your Comment',
    // remove "Text or HTML to be displayed after the set of comment fields"
    'comment_notes_after' => '',
    // redefine your own textarea (the comment body)
    'comment_field'       => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . _x( 'Comment', 'noun' ) . '</label><br /><textarea id="comment" name="comment" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>',
);

comment_form( $comments_args );
```

Answer (score 0):

If the video is embedded in a normal post, you just switch on the option leave comments below your posts when editing or writing a post.
You don't see that ? On the right of your edit post on top of the page, you can click on show/hide options. Check Comments.